# How do I specify max results for a filter query in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to retrieve the first 500 results from a large database that match a given filter query.

At the moment I'm using the following (terribly inefficient) method..

```
results = Entries.objects.filter(text__icontains="somequery")[0:500]
```

But I think this query loads the entire database in memory and then truncates the results. It's terribly slow.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's the way to do it.

The SQL generated uses `LIMIT` so it's not loading the entire database into memory and being python sliced.

Note that you can see what SQL django is writing by using `django.db.connection.queries`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

But a lesser known trick is to print a `queryset.query` or call `sql = queryset.query.__str__()`

```
>>> results = Entries.objects.filter(text__icontains="somequery")[0:500]
>>> print results.query
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIKE ... LIMIT 500
```

Comment: If there are less than 500 queries in database will it raise the error?

Comment: @DarKnight python's behavior on list ranges is to not raise any errors. `QuerySet` replicates this behavior. `[][0:1000]` will not raise errors for example.